# How to format a subject line with indent?

Tags: formatting

I'd like a subject like similar to the following but I can't figure out the indentation:

```
Re:    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
       eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're setting a letter. You can just put the reference text inside a fixed-width `\par`agraph `box` that is `[t]`op-aligned:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

My address

\bigskip

\makebox[30pt][l]{Re:}%
\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-30pt}{\strut%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.%
}

\bigskip

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

`Re:` is set `l`eft-aligned inside a fixed-width `\makebox` of width `30pt`. This allows one to calculate the exact width required for the `\parbox`: `\linewidth-30pt` and make it fully-justified with the other text components on the page.